# ASP.NET ERROR : Keyword not supported: 'provider'

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sql-server-2005, connection-string

My app fails at this line of code:

```
Dim objConnection As New SqlConnection(Application("ConnString"))
```

My connection string is:

```
"Server=testAITSQL;Database=SSCommerce;UID=PlanoWebApp;PWD=XXXXXXXX;"
```

I googled this problem and the solution for it was having a malformed connection string where the "provider" was being specified when it shouldn't have. Example conn string:

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;DATABASE=APInquiry;SERVER=SqlServer
```

I'm not specifying the Provider so I think I have a different problem...???

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but when you're debugging and break on the first line you posted, you're sure Application("ConnString") is what you expect?

Comment: Also, do you have multiple connection strings in your config file?

Comment: SQL 2005. Error: [System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider']. I do have multiple conn strings and they are nearly identical, so I still don't understand where 'provider' is coming from. Application("ConnString") does in fact show my correct conn string when I place a break there.  NOTE: *** this app runs fine when I run it locally, but it fails with the above error when I moved it to my 'test' server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your test server have the exact same configuration file as your development machine?  I suspect the configuration file on your test machine may have a different set of values for `ConnString` than you are expecting.

Comment: yes. this is likely the problem. seems obvious when one actually reads the question ;-)

Comment: @Sky - The way I've been reading questions today, I'll be happy to get one right :)

Comment: the app on the test server had it's own global.asa, and i merged my changes into a sub-directory of that app with it's own global.asax (didn't know that was possible - app is classic asp though, and my changes were .NET). anyway, the app's global was overwriting my global.

Answer (score 1):

`Provider=xxxx` is not a valid .net connection string token.

You are already implicitly specifying the provider by instantiating a SqlConnection.

Drop the provider pair and you will be golden.

Comment: Assuming @user408869 posted the right connection string, @user408869 said they weren't using Provider in the conn string

Comment: @lit - right you are. I think the fact that you actually read the question might have something to do with your likely correct answer. ;-)

Comment: When all is said and done, you may end up being technically correct as well, which is the best kind of correct

Answer (score 0):

maybe, for sh!7s and giggles, try Application("ConnString").tostring

You are connecting to a SQL Server, right? 
My ConnString has the following options:
Server
Database
User ID
Password

Comment: Which thing doesnt work? The .tostring() or using the 4 keywords I provided?

Comment: EG: Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;User ID=Username;Password=PWD;

Comment: The ToString didn't work and I checked my conn string for the 4 keywords too.